# stl algorithm in class

Tags: c++, stl

Is there a way to use stl algorithms like find() and find_if() in a container of objects?
Ex.:With find() find the element whit name "abc" in a vector of class Alfhabetic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define a comparing predicate (functor). Here is a generic implementation:

```
struct AlphabeticNameComp
{
   AlphabeticNameComp( const std::string& toCompare)
      : toCompare_( toCompare) { }

   bool operator()( const Alphabetic& obj) const
   {
       return toCompare_ == obj.name();
   }

private:
   const std::string toCompare_;
};
```

In a vector of Alphabetic elements

```
std::vector< Alphabetic> vect;
```

you can run a search like:

```
std::find_if( vect.begin(), vect.end(), AlphabeticNameComp( "abc"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define an `operator==()` for class `Alfhabetic` that matches only the data member `abc`

something like that:

```
bool operator==(const Alfhabetic& a, const Alfhabetic& b)
{
    return (a.abc == b.abc);
}
```

and then finding an `Alfhabetic` instance initialized with `abc` as the value you want.